# Prestone yellow bottle coolant vs old green coolant

Tags: coolant, cooling-system

98 civic ex has always had “green” coolant. Now not sure if that’s original used stuff or what.

However I noticed you can’t really find regular old green coolant that uses silicates and had to be replaced every 2 years.

I found a bottle of Prestone that says it’s compatible with ANY vehicle old or new. I’m curious what this coolant has in it that makes it so compatible and the difference from the regular old green coolant and other coolants.

Is it using phosphates as corrosion inhibitors? If so and a car was designed to use the old green coolant with silicates, does mixing the two only make it a 2 year long coolant since there will be silicates in there?

Comment: Your Civic *should* use Honda Blue coolant. I realize the Prestone *says* you can use it in any, but I wouldn't use anything but Honda (or Honda *type*, as there are aftermarket versions) coolant in your Honda. It seems that head gaskets in Honda cars like to get leaks in them when using any other. This is just my suggestion, though.

Comment: But this year Civic didn’t come with the blue Honda coolant from the factory